# Are there any apps for easy Part 135 Flight Time and Duty Period calculations?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-planning, time, far-135

I need a solution to quickly and easily assist me in calculating Part 135 duty time.

I am a charter broker and presently use estimations for my own consideration, but rely on advice from operators to provide informed consultation to clients.

It takes me too long to arrive at my own estimations, and I feel like there would be a tool out there designed to save me time. I saw a couple of apps in the App Store, but I wasn't impressed and would like your opinions.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an app either. If there are websites people use for this, open to give it a try, as well as consider any other tools recommended to help me be more efficient and informed. *It is possible that I am just not educated on the variables enough to effectively use the apps that I found. I have never had any formal flight training. I'm no Pilot and have never worked for a charter Operator. However, I do have a long background in aviation and know a thing or two. Learning more every day! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We generally [don't answer resource location ('shopping') questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because there are too many variables and opinions, and apps come and go all the time. Having said that, I know very little about part 135 and perhaps there's a *de facto* standard tool out there. If you don't get a useful answer here, you might get a better response in a discussion forum.